# CakePHP Using FilterComponent "Fatal Error: Cannot access empty property"

Tags: cakephp, filter, before-filter

I'm tired. I searched several components and plugins to implement a simple table with filters. CakePHP is a beauty to those who dominate, but for beginners are headaches. I am begginer :S

After trying several with disastrous results, as none works as the authors say that should work.
I am now using fully FilterCommponent of [James Fairhurst](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_filter_component/).

I have faith that someone can help. Please!

I get Fatal Error:

*Error:  Cannot access empty property*

*File:  //lib/Cake/View/View.php*

*Line:  843*

**File AppControlller:**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {

public function isAuthorized($user) {
// Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role 
return true;
}
var $_Filter = array();
var $components = array('Session','Filter');
var $_Form_options_datetime = array();

function beforeFilter() {
// for index actions
if($this->action == 'index') {
    // setup filter component
    $this->_Filter = $this->Filter->process($this);
    $url = $this->Filter->url;
    if(empty($url)) {
        $url = '/';
    }
    $this->set('filter_options',array('url'=>array($url)));
    // setup default datetime filter option
    $this->_Form_options_datetime = array('type'=>'date','dateFormat'=>'DMY','empty'=>'-','minYear'=>date("Y")-2,'maxYear'=>date("Y"));
    // reset filters
    if(isset($this->data['reset']) || isset($this->data['cancel'])) {
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
}
}

function process_datetime($fieldname) {
    $selected = null;
    if(isset($this->params['named'][$fieldname])) {
        $exploded = explode('-',$this->params['named'][$fieldname]);
        if(!empty($exploded)) {
            $selected = '';
            foreach($exploded as $k=>$e) {
                if(empty($e)) {
                    $selected .= (($k==0) ? '0000' : '00');
                } else {
                    $selected .= $e;
                }
                if($k!=2) {$selected.='-';}
            }
        }
    }
return $selected;
}
}
```

**File ServicesController:**

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');


class ServicesController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session','Paginator');
public $components = array('Session','Filter');
public $name = 'Services';


public function index() {

$this->set('service', array_merge($this->_Form_options_datetime, array('selected'=>$this->process_datetime('Service.fecha_reg'))));

$this->set('service', array_merge($this->_Form_options_datetime, array('selected'=>$this->process_datetime('Service.fecha_mod'))));

$this->Service->recursive = 0;

$this->set('service', $this->paginate(null, $this->_Filter));

}
```

**File index.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->$form->create('Service',array('action'=>'index','id'=>'filters')); ?> //Nuevo codigo

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id','ID', $filter_options); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('nombre', 'Nombre', $filter_options);?>  </th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('precio', 'Precio', $filter_options);?>  </th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('duracion', 'Duración', $filter_options);?>      </th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('fecha_mod', 'Modificado', $filter_options);?>  </th>
    <th>Acciones</th>       
    </tr>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo $this->form->input('nombre'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->form->input('precio'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->form->input('duracion'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->form->input('fecha_mod', $date_options_created); ?></th>
    //<th><?php echo $this->form->input('modified', $date_options_modified); ?></th>
    <th>
        <button type="submit" name="data[filter]" value="filter">Filtro</button>
        <button type="submit" name="data[reset]" value="reset">Reinicio</button>
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $count=0; ?>
<?php foreach($services as $service): ?>                
<?php $count ++;?>
<?php if($count % 2): echo '<tr>'; else: echo '<tr class="zebra">' ?>
<?php endif; ?>

    <td><?php echo $service['Service']['id'] ?></td>

    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link( $service['Service']['nombre'], array('action'=>'ver', $service['Service']['id']),array('escape' => false) );?></td>

    <td><?php echo $service['Service']['precio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $service['Service']['duracion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $service['Service']['fecha_mod']; ?></td>
    <td>

    <?php echo $this->Html->image('ver-24px.png', array('title' => 'Ver registro','alt' => 'Ver registro', 'border' => '0','url'=>array('action' => 'ver',$service['Service']['id']))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('editar-24px.png', array('title' => 'Editar registro','alt' => 'Editar registro', 'border' => '0','url'=>array('action' => 'editar',$service['Service']['id']))); ?>      

    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->postLink(
        $this->Html->image('/app/img/borrar-24px.png', array(
            'alt' => 'Borrar registro',
            'title' => 'Borrar registro', 
            'border' => '0')),          
            array('action' => 'eliminar',$service['Service']['id']),
            array('escape' => false,'confirm' => '¿Seguro que quieres elminarlo?')); 
    ?>  

    </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($service); ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the plugin you are using, but have a look at https://github.com/CakeDC/search, you might find it interesting.

Comment: Ps. can you post the trace of the error? There is an Error in the View, but I have no idea what is happening over there. What version of Cake are you using? 2.x I presume? So, a trace would be helpful to debug the variable it is using. Also, can you post Line 843 of the View.php with some context around it? Maybe it's a common problem.

Comment: ServicesController::index() - APP/Controller/ServicesController.php, line 12
    ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
    Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 490
    Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 185
    Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 160
    [main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 108

Comment: **FILE: App/lib/View/View.php**

'public function __set($name, $value) {
  switch ($name) {
   case 'output':
    return $this->Blocks->set('content', $value);
   default:
    $this->{$name} = $value; // LINE 843
  }
 }'

Comment: About of CakeDC fail too! and the search is complex (search as Wikipedia ). I need only filtered items on the data table. Simply this! NOT THERE NOTHING IN ALL WEB!

Comment: Jelmer, you found something else?

Answer (score 0):

Hi what about implementing this filter but **client-side**?

I mean `JavaScript + jQuery + DataTables`. [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) is a really simple plugin that allows you to make a filter in the easiest possible way.

And you can have different types of data sources (an HTML table, JSON objects or even you can use an Ajax call, which means you can have an action in your CakePHP Controller to retrieve a list of objects in JSON format).

I did a video with an example about how to call an action of CakePHP from an Ajax call: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lV6EFXiljBw&index=7&list=PLSUqL2t8VZCqPhogGoP85QcrvmTgW2_VK

I hope you find useful this information.
Regards.

Comment: Guys, please keep it English so that we can understand it as well. Ps. this is a bad idea since it won't work with pagination.

Comment: Jelmer this options fail too. I continue tried more!

Comment: @hmaceves Please talk in English, how are people who don't speak your native language able to understand what you already figured out?

Comment: Sorry! You're right. But we have not found anything. Jelmer, you found something else?